# Blender gpu renders turn completely gray

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

Whenever i try to render with gpu in blender it all turns completly gray, i have no idea why, but with cpu, it turns out just fine

Im using: AMD Radeon 200 series. Blender 2.78

**The exact same renders but with cpu and gpu.**

(CPU)
[image]
(GPU)
[image]

Comment: Hmm... that is odd. Try adding a light source to the scene that lights up the cube. Whether or not that works, this is not normal behavior. Possible GPU problem?

Comment: See here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#opencl and follow the link to wikipedia to check if your card is compatible

Comment: AMD GPUs have a long history of issues with Cycles, what you are experiencing is one of them: http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=radeon+gpu+ try updating/downgrading the drivers or stick to rendering on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

So I have an AMD Radeon HD 7800 series video card. It worked wonderfully for rendering gpu in Blender up  until 2.78 came out. Once 2.78 came out, I lost complete ability to render with GPU up until 2.78b. It kept giving me errors when I would try to render it. Once 2.78b came, the errors stopped, but I had the same gray render that you have. I decided to boost the light significantly, and try rendering again. It works, you can now see the object with the boosted light. You'll have to boost your lighting to use current version GPU for AMD, and it'll have significantly more noise. It will also be way over exposed if you render this same scene with cpu with the boosted light settings. I hope they fix it soon.[image]