# Camera problem, i tried everything it just won't render 2D objects

Tags: rendering, camera, 2d

So i tried to make some 2D characters, i created their bones and link them but soon i realized blender have a problem rendering 2D models.
here is a link for my blend file:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/eb1ei73yjwkhx8y/0.blend/file

so, what's wrong with my blend file? I really gave it up on this one, there is no reason for being unable to render 2D models.
please answer me and tell me the reason, what was wrong with it. I am very interested to learn (since i tried even from lighting to anything else without any luck)
Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I opened your file, pressed F12 and this is the result, so nothing is wrong in your file, nor Blender has problems rendering 2D models.

[image]

Comment: but why when i go to render>render image it appears only a gray image?

Comment: @giannis196 Maybe this is a probable reason? Did you search for gray rendering? [Blender gpu renders turn completely gray](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74870/blender-gpu-renders-turn-completely-gray)

Comment: Whenever i choose cpu or gpu if i go with the mouse render>render image
i only get a gray image while if i press f12 i get a normal image and i don't know why, it's like there is no explain with that...probably blender prefers keyboard than mouse LoL

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't understand at first. Maybe you should explicitly explain that in the original question? The question reads as if you think Blender could generally not at all render 2D objects - but if it does render when pressing F12, but not when you select it from the menu, that's a totally different story.

Comment: It's a strange behaviour, that I wasn't able to recreate, probably a bug, but you can solve it creating  a new file, going to file > Append, double click on your file, double click on collection, select the only collection present and click append. You can append the world also, to get back the same lighting.

Comment: ok, that's weird...does it render from cpu when i press f12 and from gpu when i go to render>render image?
why does it even matter if i do it by pressing f12 or by going to render>render image??

Comment: I could render both gpu and cpu, even in your original file. The difference between F12 and menu shouldn't exist at all, probably a bug.